# ClientSideValidations Not Show in Twitter Bootstrap-Modal Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, client-side-validation

i using clientsidevalidations gem and twitter bootstrap-modal for my app.
but vaidations not working.

on application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-modal
```

this is element for show in modal dialog

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >

  <%= form_for @content, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <script>$('#new_content').validate()</script>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">New Content</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style = "height:600px;overflow-y: scroll;">

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :permalink, "Permalink" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :permalink %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "redactor", :rows => 10, :cols => 40 %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>&nbsp;&nbsp; atau &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= f.submit ( "Submit" ), :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-medium" %>
  </div>

  </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

when i check the elements on chrome

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/contents" class="new_content" data-validate="true" id="new_content" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

I found some solutions but it did not help me

[solution but not working to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073357/simpleformclientsidevalidationsbootstrap-validation-is-not-occuring-on-the-f) and
[modal view](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/339)

Are there any other solutions?
thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using SimpleForm and SimpleForm's Bootstrap integration. From there you can use client_side_validations-simple_form which supports Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: thx brian for answer, is this what you mean? https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-simple_form ok i will try it..

Answer (score 5):

Its an issue with input fields not being visible when the validation handlers are attached. See [SimpleForm+ClientSideValidations+bootstrap - Validation is not occuring on the form- all inputs are accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073357/simpleformclientsidevalidationsbootstrap-validation-is-not-occuring-on-the-f) for details and a fix.