# Client side validation in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have client side validation,but some why it doesnt works in twitter bootstrap modal window. If i put my form just somewhere else then modal, then it works like a charm. Is there something i've missed?

Here is my form code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade invite-modal" data-backdrop="true">
          <%= simple_form_for User.new, url: :invite_teacher_organizations, validate: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :full_name,  required:true, validate: { :presence => true, :message => "Name cant be blank" }, placehold: "John Doe" %>
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, validate: { presence: true}%>
        <%= f.submit 'Send Invite', class: 'btn-primary' %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073357/simpleformclientsidevalidationsbootstrap-validation-is-not-occuring-on-the-f